# how to add a line break to this javascript command

Tags: javascript, html

okay I have a script that outpouts an array like so

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg;
```

the result I get is

```
line1 line2 line3 line4
```

I want it to be like this

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

I have tried adding the  in various places but just cant get it to work

my full code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(a){
var msg="";
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
msg+= a[i]+"\n";
}

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("</br>");

}
</script>
</head>
<title>
Welcome To ....
</title>
<body>
<center><h1> WELCOME TO .... </h1></center>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<center><form>
<textarea rows="7" cols="60" name="alpha"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button"
value="show array"
onclick="showArray(textareaToArray(this.form.alpha ))">
</form></center>
</br>
<div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `join()`:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join('<br>');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9Xxa/)

**Edit according to OP's comment**

You don't need to loop through the array when using join:

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9Xxa/1/)

```
function textareaToArray(text){
    return text.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}

function showArray(msg){
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("<br/>");
}
```

Also you don't have specified a doctype... That's very important.
For HTML5 use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: I just get a blank page using this bro

Comment: How does your array look like? Is it really an array?

Comment: I will paste my full script above so you can see how I am handling the array